# Debug Program received signal "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
NSString *aCount = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl countc:aCount ];
```

Program received signal "SIGABRT" at  the line which  "*aCount" is set, How can i debug(solve) this type of error?

Comment: countc:aCount or count:aCount? if count parameter is integer type tyen use [aCount intValue].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that database column has a value of null. you need to first check for null before using when you are dealing with sqlite.

Do something like this -

```
if ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4))
{
    NSString *aCount = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities for that exception, check with following...

1. The column might be representing INTEGER in database and in code it is being treated as VARCHAR.
2. The column might have NULL value and that is tried to convert into NSString.

Comment: The column is VARCHAR and it is not NULL

Answer (score 0):

print the nsstrings and also check the initwithname function